# How static const data inside shared library located is accessed in C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, libgcrypt

In libgcrypt shared library, during AES encryption/decryption operation lookup tables are accessed.
In case  of AES encryption, 1KB lookup table ( defined as  static const u32 encT inside shared library)
and in case  of AES decryption, 1KB + 256 Byte lookup table ( defined as

```
static const struct
{
  u32 T[256];
  byte inv_sbox[256];
} dec_tables inside shared library) are used.
```

Being a static member of shared library, where encT and dec_tables will be placed ?
 At code secion or any other section ?

when I check with nm command ,  it shows r , means read only.

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep encT
00091ae0 r encT

nm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep dec_tables
000915e0 r dec_tables
```

Is read-only section and code section are same with respect to shared library ?

I have made a sample program to perform AES decryption and to know what is the control flow
of the program to perform AES decryption.

```
gcryError = gcry_cipher_decrypt(
    gcryCipherHd, // gcry_cipher_hd_t
    dec_out,    // void *
    txtLength,    // size_t
    enc_out,    // const void *
    txtLength);   // size_t
```

Here is what I found ,

```
 gcry_cipher_decrypt (visibility.c ) -->
 _gcry_cipher_decrypt (cipher.c) -->
 static cipher_decrypt (cipher.c) --> 
 static  do_ecb_decrypt  (cipher.c) --> 
 static do_ecb_crypt  (cipher.c) --> 
 static do_decrypt  (rijndael.c) --> 
 static do_decrypt_fn  (rijndael.c)
```

Inside, do_decrypt_fn function final decryption operations are performed by accessing  dec_tables.T and dec_tables.inv_sbox.

```
     // few lines are added for reference
static unsigned int
do_decrypt_fn (const RIJNDAEL_context *ctx, unsigned char *b,
               const unsigned char *a)
{
      sb[3] ^= rol(decT[(byte)(sa[3] >> (0 * 8))], (0 * 8));
      sa[0] ^= rol(decT[(byte)(sa[3] >> (1 * 8))], (1 * 8));
      sa[1] ^= rol(decT[(byte)(sa[3] >> (2 * 8))], (2 * 8));
      sa[2] ^= rol(decT[(byte)(sa[3] >> (3 * 8))], (3 * 8));
      sa[3] = rk[1][3] ^ sb[3];

      /* Last round is special. */
      sb[0] = inv_sbox[(byte)(sa[0] >> (0 * 8))] << (0 * 8);
      sb[1] = inv_sbox[(byte)(sa[0] >> (1 * 8))] << (1 * 8);
      sb[2] = inv_sbox[(byte)(sa[0] >> (2 * 8))] << (2 * 8);
      sb[3] = inv_sbox[(byte)(sa[0] >> (3 * 8))] << (3 * 8);
      sa[0] = sb[0] ^ rk[0][0];
```

Here,  dec_tables is defined inside rijndael-tables.h and this header file is included inside rijndael.c file.

```
     static const struct
    {
      u32 T[256];
      byte inv_sbox[256];
    } dec_tables =
      {
        {
          0x50a7f451, 0x5365417e, 0xc3a4171a, 0x965e273a,
          0xcb6bab3b, 0xf1459d1f, 0xab58faac, 0x9303e34b,
          ...},
           {
          0x52,0x09,0x6a,0xd5,0x30,0x36,0xa5,0x38,
          0xbf,0x40,0xa3,0x9e,0x81,0xf3,0xd7,0xfb,
          ...}


#define decT dec_tables.T
#define inv_sbox dec_tables.inv_sbox
```

Here is my questions to you.

1. Being a static type , all these static functions and static data
   dec_tables are not visible outside shared library module. Then how they are located to use in decryption?
2. **I think this OFFSET of encT and dec_tables are used by some function or in some calculation to  locate dec_tables to perform the
   AES decryption.**   Am I right ?
3. Can anyone explain using readelf/objdump/nm or other way, how shared
   library use these OFFSET to locate the static data (encT/dec_tables)
   used for AES encryption/decryption ?

Or

4. is these OFFSET useful in any sense to locate encT/dec_tables static
   data ?

I don't know how GOT or PLT works with OFFSET . Is there any way to use these OFFSET with respect to GOT/PLT to locate these static data ?

I am using Ubuntu 16.06, gcc-4.9.

Any link/ sample program solve the above doubts will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with reading the [shared library bible](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: The lowercase `r` in `nm` output tells you where the linker puts it: `00091ae0 r encT`. The `r` means [the symbol is in a read only data section](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm). It is just initialized data.